# A Route Assignment Program

Tags: c#, java, routes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A Route Assignment Program Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115086/a-route-assignment-program-algorithm)

This is more of an information question.
Basically what im trying to do, is create a program that will assign a route for a driving test. there will be three diffrent routes, linked together at certain points. Never should there be more than one student at a point of intersection.

The program will probably have to know the length in time, between each point and also the total distance of each route in time.

My question being whats the best way about coding this, i was thinking of C# as it seems a little easier and theres more about c# on the web.

Any help here would be appreciated.

[image: Three Routes, Containing points of intersection]

So heres the process.

1. Student Requests a test.
2. Student enters contact details
3. System checks availability of time and date. Avoiding a clash
4. System assigns an examiner for the test.
5. System assigns a route for the test.